# Subdomain not working on Apache2/Debian9

Tags: apache, dns, subdomain, virtual-server

I would like to set up a subdomain on my virtual server with Debian 9 and Apache 2 which points to a directory at /var/www/html/test.
SSL and Let's Encrypt is also enabled, so the subdomain should be reached with https too.

My `000-default.conf` file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
        ServerName www.example.com
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
        </IfModule>
        SSLEngine on
        ServerAlias www.example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

The file `default-ssl.conf` looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        <VirtualHost *:443>
                ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

                DocumentRoot /var/www/html

                SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
                SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem

                ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
                CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

                SSLEngine on

                <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </FilesMatch>
                <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
                                SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
                </Directory>

                ServerName www.example.com
                ServerAlias example.com
        </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

I made a new copy of the `000-default.conf` file, named it "test.example.com.conf" and enabled it by means of a2ensite. The file looks like:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>

        ServerAdmin webmaster@test.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

# vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/test
        ServerName test.example.com
        <IfModule mod_headers.c>
                Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload"
        </IfModule>
        SSLEngine on
        ServerAlias test.example.com
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
        Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

My `hosts` file includes the entry `SERVER_IP_ADDRESS   test.example.com`.

The DNS server has an "A"-Entry with test.example.com pointing on `SERVER_IP_ADDRESS`.

Pinging test.example.com from another machine ends in "Host not found" and a ping on the virtual server results in an response from itself.

**So why does the webbrowser only show "Server not found"?
Did I forget something? Is something in my config wrong?**

Comment: If `Pinging test.example.com from another machine ends in "Host not found"` and `The DNS server has an "A"-Entry with test.example.com pointing on SERVER_IP_ADDRESS` then either that another machine has DNS service misconfigured or DNS server is not properly configured.

Comment: Yes you are right, the update of the DNS-Server took some time.
Now i get a response from the server!
But when i view the page test.example.com in browser it shows the same content as the main page www.example.com.
What could cause this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long testing and research I found the mistake!
There were 3:

1. The DNS A-entry took some time to complete
2. my .htaccess forwarding caused the URL always to be rewritten to www.example.com, no matter which subdomain was typed in
3. my `test.example.com.conf` file has a mistake in it which makes the subdomain only available via https: the ServerAlias instruction was missing inside `<VirtualHost _default_:80>`

So it works so far and needs some improvements...

I hope I will help someone else with my mistakes!